# Navigating QWebview in non-touch symbian phones

Tags: qt, qt4, navigation, symbian, qwebview

Our Qt application for Symbian (3rd ed FP1/Fp2, 5th ed n Symbian^3) is complete except for few fixes!

Qt doesn't seem to support key navigation in QWebview for 3rd ed phones! https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTWEBKIT-271

!. How can I navigate through the webpage using navigation keys in non-touch phones?
2. Is there any way to access the next clickable element (like links, login/password input areas) in the QWebview? (so that I can implement navigation by handling kb events)

Currently I have a cursor in the webview using which I click on links, scroll etc, but that's not at all user friendly :(, please help me find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work, then it's not implemented in whatever QtWebKit version you are using. The linked bug specifically mentions QtWebKit 2.1 so I guess you just have to update to that version.